# Bit-Shift array of Bits into Int Variable

Tags: c, arrays, bitwise-operators

So I'm not sure if this is the easiest way to accomplish what my end goal is, so if anyone has a better suggestion, feel free to throw it at me.  I've tried searching both on here, and with Google, but I can't seem to figure out how to do this.

I have an array of int values: `int bitVal[8]`

In my program, each of these values is 1 bit, within a byte.  I need to create a loop which goes through each value, and bit shift the value into the int variable.

I tried this as a simple test:

```
int t = 0;
int e = 1;
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    t <<= e;
    printf("%d\n", t);
}
```

Now I know that if I had a variable that had a byte value of `0000 0010` and I do `var <<= 1;` the result will be `0000 0100`.  Is there a way to set it so the shifted bit is a 1 instead of a 0?

Comment: Since `t` is `0` shifting it remains `0`. The question is not very clear. `int bitVal[8]` is not in the code snippet, and the loop constraint is the curious `i < 3;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably overthinking it. You can shift in one bit at a time, regardless whether it is a 0 or 1. All it needs is a loop such as this:

```
result = 0;
for (i=0; i<8; i++)
{
    result = (result<<1) | bitVal[i];
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  You're right, I was completely overthinking it T_T

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to set it so the shifted bit is a 1 instead of a 0?

No, not as such.  Instead, what you do is shift the target value to make room, and then combine with the value you want to add.  For example, if `x` is your accumulation variable and `y` contains a value that you are certain is either 0 or 1, then you might do this:

```
x = (x << 1) | y;
```